# Exchange 2013 , edb files

Tags: exchange

Is it possible when databases are mounted and working to open an windows explorer window , navigate where edb files are stored and delete them?

I am just curious.

I hope when the edb file is in mounted state operating system won't let user delete it without a warning…

Answer (score 4):

You can't delete *any* file while it's in use.
Mounted database files are in use.
The O.S. will not let you delete them.

---

You can, however, manually delete transaction log files, as soon as they are no longer actively used. But if you do, sooner or later this *will* come to bite you back.

Comment: ...did you just answer in haiku?

Comment: No, but I wish I had.

Comment: In use files cannot / 
be deleted while in use. /
Mounted is in use. --in haiku

Comment: (If someone SAYS haiku, I have to WRITE haiku.  It's a rule.)

Comment: @KatherineVillyard You. I like you.